# Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool - Copy Into Failing With Odd error - Python

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, azure-synapse

I'm getting an error when attempting to insert from a temp table into a table that exists in Synapse, here is the relevant code:

```
    def load_adls_data(self, schema: str, table: str, environment: str, filepath: str, columns: list) -> str:
        if self.exists_schema(schema):
            if self.exists_table(schema, table):

                if environment.lower() == 'prod':
                    schema = "lvl0"
                else:
                    schema = f"{environment.lower()}_lvl0"

                temp_table = self.generate_temp_create_table(schema, table, columns)

                sql0 = """
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CopyDataFromADLS') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #CopyDataFromADLS;
    END
"""

                sql1 = """
{}
COPY INTO #CopyDataFromADLS FROM 
'{}'
WITH  
( 
    FILE_TYPE = 'CSV',
    FIRSTROW = 1
)
INSERT INTO {}.{}
SELECT *, GETDATE(), '{}' from #CopyDataFromADLS

""".format(temp_table, filepath, schema, table, Path(filepath).name)
                print(sql1)

                conn = pyodbc.connect(self._synapse_cnx_str)
                conn.autocommit = True

                with conn.cursor() as db:

                    db.execute(sql0)
                    db.execute(sql1)
```

If I get rid of the insert statement and just do a select from the temp table in the script:

```
SELECT * FROM #CopyDataFromADLS
```

I get the same error in either case:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Not able to validate external location because The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict. (105215) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I've run the generated code for both the insert and the select in Synapse and they ran perfectly. Google has no real info on this so could someone assist with this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Not able to validate external location because The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict. (105215) (SQLExecDirectW)')

- This error occurs mostly because of authentication or access.
- Make sure you have blob storage contributor access.
- In the copy into script, add the authentication key for blob storage, unless it is a public blob storage.
- I tried to repro this using copy into statement without authentication and got the same error.

[image]

- After adding authentication using SAS key data is copied successfully.
  [image]

Refer the **Microsoft document** for  [permissions required for bulk load using copy  into statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/copy-into-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest#permissions).